# MySQL: NOT IN with sub select not working as expected?

Tags: mysql, subquery

This is my query:

```
SELECT customer_email 
FROM   sales_flat_order 
WHERE  customer_email NOT IN (SELECT customer_email
                              FROM   sales_flat_order
                              WHERE  status != 'holded');
```

There are 3 rows with status `holded` for my test `customer_email` test@example.com, no other status for that mail. For some reason, the full query returns no matches. When I fill the NOT IN manually like that, it works, I get my 3 rows:

```
SELECT customer_email 
FROM   sales_flat_order 
WHERE  customer_email NOT IN ('whatever', 'foobar', '123@456.com');
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f990a09528d82d7bb4e72530a5de59ec

The fiddle works as expected though, my table is much bigger, but the columns are of the same type.

Thanks!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You should provide some sample data here.

Comment: Fiddle provided in my post, sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make the assumption that there is at least one record in `sales_flat_order` that satisfies condition `status != 'holded'` and whose `customer_email` is `NULL`.

`(NOT) IN` is notoriously tricky with `NULL`s, here is an example.

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 1 NOT IN (SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3)
```

This yields a record with value `1`, as expected.

However if you change that to:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 1 NOT IN (SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT NULL)
```

Then the query produces an empty result set. This is a well-known problem with `(NOT) IN`. For this reason, you should generally avoid this syntax, and use `(NOT) EXISTS` instead. The above query could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT 1 a
FROM (SELECT 1 a) t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (SELECT 2 a UNION ALL SELECT NULL) t2
    WHERE t1.a = t2.a
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=373cb201b532fb7d8cbbe2bb1dc2ea87)**

For your query:

```
SELECT customer_email 
FROM sales_flat_order s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM sales_flat_order s1
    WHERE s1.customer_email = s.customer_email AND s.status != 'holded'
);
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right, there are NULLs in the DB! Is this query significantly slower?

Comment: @Arnie: no, I don't expect that to be slower than your current query. For performance, you want an index on `sales_flat_order(customer_email, status )`